# Using ADF to move data between SQL and CosmosDB, with complex Data Conversion

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I am trying to move data between an Azure SQL Database and a Cosmos DB in ADF. But as far as I can see the Copy activity does not allow me to make any changes to the data. The Data Flow option, only allows me to use predetermined functions. (Abs, cos, aso.)

I have created an Azure Function that contains the math I need for my transformation. I will try to illustrate with an example.

Result from SQL query (might have more than one record):

```
id = 1,
int1 = 4,
int2 = 3
```

Then I need the function to use `int1, int2` as parameters for my Azure Function. And the object I need to insert into my Cosmos DB would look something like:

```
id = 1,
int1 = 4,
int2 = 3,
Calculated1 = AzureFunction.Result[0]
Calculated2 = AzureFunction.Result[1]
```

The scenario I have is a bit more complex, but this is the bare minimum. Can this be done in ADF?

Comment: Data Flow is almost certainly the correct approach, and its expressions can execute complex mathematical operations. Can you post an example of such a formula?

Comment: Hi @Steffen Hvid, not very sure what's the function method do, is it a complex data conversion to get `Calculate1` and `Calculate2`?

Comment: I am converting coordinates from degrees to ETRS89, and the math to this is to complex for me to do the actual calculation. Luckely there exist a library, that can convert this. Hence i need to use an Azure function to make my calculation. But it is not important what that function does. In principles a solution could be just pass data into an azure function, then return the data to cosmos db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your scenario, not very sure how you do the data conversion, there are two workarounds.

**Workaround 1:**

If it's very complex, then  you could do like this: Look up active + Azure Function:

1. Lookup active: run the SQL query to get the result.
2. Azure Function: pass the lookup output to the function, function do
   the data conversion and transfer the data into Cusmos DB.

Pipeline overview:

[image]

**Workaround 2:**

If the data conversion is not complex, then you could do that with [Data Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-create).

1. Source: SQL database run the query as source.
2. [Derived Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column): create the new columns `Calculate1` and
   `Calculate2`, build the [expression/function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions) to get the data you
   want.
3. Sink: set the Custom DB as sink.

Data Flow overview:

[image]

HTH.

Comment: Thank you for you input. I have decided to actually just do a copy 1-1 to CosmosDB, then create the function to select all records that does not contain the transformed data. And the convert it. This makes it possible to run my calculations after the fact, and my copy activity is not dependen on the functions availability.